# Find the value of $\cot^{-1}21+\cot^{-1}13+\cot^{-1}(-8)$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

> Find the value of $\cot^{-1}21+\cot^{-1}13+\cot^{-1}(-8)$

**My Attempt**
\begin{align}
\cot^{-1}21+\cot^{-1}13+\cot^{-1}(-8)&=\pi-\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{8}+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{13}+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{21}\\
&=\pi-\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{8}+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{13}+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{21}\\
&=\pi-\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{8}+\tan^{-1}\frac{4-3}{1+4.3}+\tan^{-1}\frac{5-4}{1+5.4}\\
&=\pi-\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{8}+\tan^{-1}5-\tan^{-1}3\\
&=\pi-\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{8}+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{8}=\pi
\end{align}
My reference gives the solution $0$, so what's going wrong with my attempt ?

Comment: Are these angles in degrees? Or real numbers?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner got to be real numbers as its not mentioned.

Comment: I think $$\pi$$ is the right result.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values  says $0<$arccot$(x)<\pi $, So, sum can not be zero

Comment: Note that there are two definitions of $\mathrm{arccot}(x)$ which differ for negative $x.$ The continuous form is $\mathrm{arccot}(x) = \pi -\mathrm{arctan}(x)$ and
the sign-symmetric form $\mathrm{arccot}(x) = \mathrm{arctan}(1/x)$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee thanx. so u mean nothing wrong with my attempt ?, yet there are posts gives $0$ as solution with no negative votes here.

Answer (score 1):

You started by noting $\cot^{-1}21=\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{21}$ etc. The problem came when you encountered a negative argument. Since all the functions of interest are odd, $\cot^{-1}(-8)=-\cot^{-1}8=-\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{8}$, no $\pi$ involved. (Another way to prove $\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{21}+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{13}=\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{8}$ is to use the identity $\tan^{-1}a+\tan^{-1}b=\tan^{-1}\frac{a+b}{1-ab}$, which for $a=1/m,\,b=1/n$ simplifies to $\tan^{-1}\frac{m+n}{mn-1}$.)

Comment: $\cot^{-1}(-8)=\pi-\cot^{-1}8\neq -\cot^{-1}8$ !!

Comment: @ss1729 The OP wanted to understand a reference that clearly uses the definition I've stuck to, on which inverse cotangents range from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ instead of $0$ to $\pi$. The latter is generally preferred for inverting the even trigonometric functions.

Comment: inverse cotangents usually have a range $\in(0,\pi)$, principal value branch, so with that definition I think $\cot^{-1}(-8)=\pi-\cot^{-1}8\neq -\cot^{-1}8$ right ?

Comment: @ss1729 Define "usually". In case you're right I googled "arccot", then went through the first page of results. [These](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcCot.html) [agree](mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseCotangent.html) [with](https://paulmasson.github.io/sagemath-docs/functions/arccot.html) me, but (continued in next comment)

Comment: @ss1729 (continued from previous comment) [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) [agree](www.mathwords.com/c/cotangent_inverse.htm) with you, and [this](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/arccot.html) mentions both conventions (but documents code that sides with me), as does [this](https://www.intmath.com/blog/mathematics/which-is-the-correct-graph-of-arccot-x-6009). Whatever convention helps the OP, that's what I use. (I'm not sure why some of those links broke.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

$$
\tan(\mbox{arccot}(a)) = \frac 1a
$$

and

$$
\tan(a+b) = \frac{\tan(a)+\tan(b)}{1-\tan(a)\tan(b)}
$$

so

$$
\tan(\mbox{arccot}(a)+\mbox{arccot}(b)) = \frac{a+b}{a b -1}
$$

etc.

NOTE

You can try now

$$
\tan(\mbox{arccot}(a)+\mbox{arccot}(b)+\mbox{arccot}(c)) = d = \frac{a (b+c)+b c-1}{abc-(a+b+c)}
$$

and then

$$
\mbox{arccot}(a)+\mbox{arccot}(b)+\mbox{arccot}(c) = \mbox{arctan}(d)
$$

after substitution we have $d=0$ and $\arctan(0) = 0$